# 3 tier application and large arraylist of objects

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, arraylist, n-tier-architecture

I have an arraylist of objects created by looping through an XML file that is returned from a URL.  Since it can be large depending on the amount of data requested by the client, I'd like to display it in pages of 50 or so in a Gridview or something similar.  It has 15 properties which are strings, dates and integers, and needs the ability to be sorted on any of them.  I don't think doing the sorting on the client side follows the 3 tier pattern.  I also don't think I should save the array list in state.  I'm new to 3 tier apps, so I'd like to get some ideas on how to preserve the original list to enable me to get the next page of data, while being able to sort the current page on any column.

Comment: Can you tag your post with the relevant language / framework?

Comment: Is the app built using ASP.NET? WPF? WinForms?

Comment: @ChrisS - what would you suggest?  Thanks.

Comment: @ketan app is built using .Net

Comment: A generic List, as ArrayLists involve boxing

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's a number of ways to skin a cat and mine may not be the best, but, if it was me, I'd probably create a service that took two integer parameters, PageIndex and PageSize, so that the client could request only what it needs. After all, the required information could be within the first 10 results, so why download 10000?

You don't say whether the XML comes from an external URL or if it's available from your site. If it's external, the first time the client requests data from the service, I'd load up the XML and store to disk. Then, the server can load it up as an XDocument and query the required data using Linq.

Something like (completely untested):

```
    public ArrayList GetObjects(int pageIndex, int pageSize)
    {
        XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("resource.xml");
        var objects = (from o in xmlDoc.Descendants() 
                       select o).Skip(pageIndex).Take(pageSize);

        // parse elements into objects and add to collection before returning
    }
```

I would have thought that would be sufficient - if there proved to be any severe performance issues with reloading the file each request then I'd revisit caching ideas as and when. Maybe I'd look into [Memory Mapped files](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/salvapatuel/archive/2009/06/08/working-with-memory-mapped-files-in-net-4.aspx) that are now supported in .NET 4, or a more rudimentary caching mechanism. I can't really speak more on those unfortunately as I'm far from being an expert on either.

Additionally, if I was using .NET 4 I'd return a strongly-typed generic collection instead of an ArrayList.

Comment: The application currently exists as a fat client - the XML comes from an external URL and is downloaded all at once.  This is a rewrite as a .Net web application, and therefore I need to limit the amount of data returned.  Additionally, I don't need all the nodes that are returned, and need to sort the current page data by any of the properties.  Can this be done with a strongly-typed generic collection?  I also thought of storing the XML on the webserver, but the data may change between calls.

Comment: If the XML is coming from an external URL outside of your control and it might change between requests, the only options I can really see are to either download it afresh for each request, or cache it for a certain period of time and give the user an option to force a hard refresh. As for sorting, the generic collections within the framework have methods for that. You could even add the sorting to your linq statement.

Comment: After more research, I changed the ArrayList to a generic list and am currently trying to figure out how to sort it by any of the object properties.